# Parse error after modifying the template menu

Tags: functions, themes, errors, parse

I made an edit in the template's `functions.php` and now I can't access my website.

I know I have to fix the problem from the Cpanel but I'm now scared to do anything because I've tried once and the screen started flashing.

This is the error I get:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected '<' in `/.../wp-content/themes/oblique/functions.php` on *line 291*

Is there anyone that can help me with this?

Comment: Contact the theme developers if it is premium theme. Or get professional help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the original copy of the theme's `functions.php` file? Replace it in order to restore access to your website.

But, as the error indicates, you have an unexpected `<` in your code on **line 291**. This means that there was an extra character added that wasn't necessary and throws off your code.

Open the `functions.php` file from your theme located in `/wp-content/themes/oblique/` on a text editor that support your text editor ([Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), etc.) scroll down to that line number and you should see the issue. Below is an example of a textpad with line numbers to give you a better visual:

[image: Sublime Text]

Comment: thanks for your propmt answer, I can't access my admin panel, I'm only allowed to fix it from the Cpanel...is this correct?

Comment: yes, i do have the copy of the functions.php

Comment: When you say "_fix it from the Cpanel_" may you elaborate or provide a screenshot so I can get a better visual? Did you also look into the line that has the error as I mentioned in my answer above?

Comment: this is the screen shot of the Cpanel/Users/adaossola/Desktop/schermata.jpg

Comment: not sure i can i send to you the screenshot..... yes I have looked the line copying the function.php into brackets ( I have mac)

Comment: with the help of a friend on mine we fixed the error modyfing the 291 line  as you suggested, thanks!

Comment: @Ada Great, glad I could help. Please make sure you click the green checkmark next to my answer and up vote it to let the community know that your question is resolved. Thanks